# NullPointerException even tho there are no null variables

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This is the code:

```
package daw.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SessionTrack extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Create a session object if it is already not created.
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        // Get session creation time.
        Date createTime = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
        // Get last access time of this web page.
        Date lastAccessTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());
        
        String title = "Welcome Back to my website";
        Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);
        String visitCountKey = new String("visitCount");
        String userIDKey = new String("userID");
        String userID = new String("ABCD");
        
        // Check if this is new comer on your web page.
        if (session.isNew()) {
            title = "Welcome to my website";
            session.setAttribute(userIDKey, userID);
        } else {
            visitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
            visitCount = visitCount + 1;
            userID = (String) session.getAttribute(userIDKey);
        }
        session.setAttribute(visitCountKey, visitCount);
        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>\n<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n"
                + "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n"
                + "<h2 align=\"center\">Session Infomation</h2>\n" + "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">\n"
                + "<tr bgcolor=\"#949494\">\n" + " <th>Session info</th><th>value</th></tr>\n" + "<tr>\n"
                + " <td>id</td>\n" + " <td>" + session.getId() + "</td></tr>\n" + "<tr>\n" + " <td>Creation Time</td>\n"
                + " <td>" + createTime + " </td></tr>\n" + "<tr>\n" + " <td>Time of Last Access</td>\n" + " <td>"
                + lastAccessTime + " </td></tr>\n" + "<tr>\n" + " <td>User ID</td>\n" + " <td>" + userID
                + " </td></tr>\n" + "<tr>\n" + " <td>Number of visits</td>\n" + " <td>" + visitCount + "</td></tr>\n"
                + "</table>\n" + "</body></html>");
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    daw.servlet.SessionTrack.doGet(SessionTrack.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    daw.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:35)
```

The code at line 37 is this:

```
visitCount = visitCount + 1;
```

Why do I get this error? I created visitCount here so it's not null (line 26):

```
Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);
```

I tried using int instead of integer but I get the same issue. Since visitCount is declared outside of the if instruction I think it should work regardless.

Comment: `visitCount` will be null when `session.getAttribute(visitCountKey)` returns null, which will very likely be the case when this GET request runs *for the first* time in the session. And `visitCount + 1` needs to unbox the Integer object, which causes that null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the variable in the line above the NPE:

```
visitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
visitCount = visitCount + 1;
```

So if there is no attribute with visitCountKey in the session, you will get null, and NPE when adding 1 to null.

Comment: As a fix, maybe the OP should use something like `visitCount = (null == visitCount ? 0 : visitCount) + 1;` or a corresponding `if` block

Comment: It depends I guess, if the visitCount is always null then I would go fix that, otherwise visitCount will always be shown as 1. If it is null only on the first visit I would have it default to 0.

Comment: You can see `session.setAttribute(visitCountKey, visitCount);` is done later somewhere in the same code.

Comment: Yeah, but we don't know if visitCount is persisted between sessions. If it defaults to 0 on null, it will be a correct visitCount within the same session at the very least. But if it was supposed to be between sessions as well, my comment above still applies.

Comment: True, but that wasn't the question. We can only assume that the OP knew what they were doing by using a session attribute rather than an application attribute. I guess the point I was making was just for you to improve your answer with a solution, in addition to explaining why it's failing.